# Как сделать флекс элементы с разной высотой?

Tags: css, flexbox

как сверстать блоки так как показано на картинке?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если размеры будут неизменные, то воспользуйтесь `grid layout`, если же будут изменться, думаю вам нужно будет `masonry`.

Answer (score 1):

С помощью `flex` можно сделать так:

```css
.container {
  width: 1040px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap column;
  height: 460px;
  gap: 50px;
  padding: 50px;
  background: #00B8C9;
}

.gallery__item {
  width: 280px;
  height: 120px;
  background: #DA5A60;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gallery__item-1 {
  height: 290px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="gallery">
    <div class="gallery__item gallery__item-1"></div>
    <div class="gallery__item"></div>
    <div class="gallery__item"></div>
    <div class="gallery__item"></div>
    <div class="gallery__item"></div>
    <div class="gallery__item"></div>
    <div class="gallery__item"></div>
    <div class="gallery__item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

С помощью `grid` можно сделать так:

```css
.container {
  width: 1040px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 50px;
  padding: 50px;
  background: #00B8C9;
}

.gallery__item {
  background: #DA5A60;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 280px;
  height: 120px;
}

.gallery__item-1 {
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  height: 290px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="gallery">
    <div class="gallery__item gallery__item-1"></div>
    <div class="gallery__item"></div>
    <div class="gallery__item"></div>
    <div class="gallery__item"></div>
    <div class="gallery__item"></div>
    <div class="gallery__item"></div>
    <div class="gallery__item"></div>
    <div class="gallery__item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```